# Relocation error: version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc

I'm implementing a transcriptomics pipeline using Conda on a Linux VM (Ubuntu 14.04.6), but I am running into issues with GCC.

I installed the latest GCC version with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
```

But when I run my pipeline, I get the error:

```
salmon: relocation error: salmon: symbol _ZNKSt3_V214error_category10_M_messageB5cxx11Ei, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

But I can see "GLIBCXX_3.4.21" is actually there when I run:

```
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLI
```

I have found a thread for a similar issue that suggests using:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
```

But then running the pipeline gives me

```
salmon: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1: version `GOMP_4.0' not found (required by salmon)
salmon: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by salmon)
salmon: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by salmon)
salmon: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by salmon)
salmon: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.11' not found (required by salmon)
salmon: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by salmon)
salmon: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by salmon)
salmon: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/parker/miniconda3/envs/RREP4/bin/../lib/libtbbmalloc_proxy.so.2)
salmon: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.11' not found (required by /home/parker/miniconda3/envs/RREP4/bin/../lib/libtbb.so.2)
salmon: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/parker/miniconda3/envs/RREP4/bin/../lib/libtbb.so.2)
salmon: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/parker/miniconda3/envs/RREP4/bin/../lib/libtbb.so.2)
```

since GCC ended up getting downgraded. Whenever I upgrade GCC back to v4.9 I end up with the initial error, going around in circles.

I am using a Linux VM that others have been working on previously and there may be multiple versions of GCC installed which may be conflicting (GCC was also installed through Conda environment). Is there a way to do a clean install/configure for GCC on Ubuntu 14.04.6?

Thanks